# Import sass :export varaiables in Next.js

Tags: typescript, sass, next.js, icss

In my Next.js app, I am including a component that accepts theme colors as a parameter.

I have sass variables defined à la

```
$primary: #f00;

:export {
  primary: $primary;
}
```

which I import in `pages/index.tsx` like

```
import colors from '../styles/_variables.scss'
```

Then I can (theoretically) use `color.primary` in my component.

In the IDE, I get the ts error: `Cannot find module '../styles/_variables.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.`

My next.config.js file looks like this

```
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
const path = require("path")

module.exports = withSass({
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  }
});
```

and if I import the scss directly with `import '../styles/global.scss'` The import works, but of course they aren't defined as a variable I can assess.

Answer (score 2):

That is just a TypeScript warning. You can declare any scss import as a module to satisfy TypeScript.

```
declare module '*.scss' {
  const content: {[key: string]: string};
  export default content;
}
```